# docker COPY after RUN mount type cache not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a Dockerfile where I first build an image as build and then use that image for another stage, as follows:

```
FROM docker.io/rust:1.71.0-slim-bookworm as build
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    lsb-release \
    wget \
    software-properties-common \
    gnupg
RUN wget https://apt.llvm.org/llvm.sh && chmod +x llvm.sh && ./llvm.sh 15
RUN apt-get install -y \
    libz-dev \
    libelf-dev \
    protobuf-compiler \
    libbpf-dev \
    linux-headers-generic \
    bpftool \
    clang \
    make \
    pkg-config
RUN rustup component add rustfmt

COPY api /home/root/workspace/api
COPY crates /home/root/workspace/crates
COPY Cargo.lock /home/root/workspace/Cargo.lock
COPY Cargo.toml /home/root/workspace/Cargo.toml

WORKDIR /home/root/workspace
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/usr/local/cargo/registry \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/home/root/workspace/target \
    cargo build --release --all-features
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/home/root/workspace/target \
    cp \
    /home/root/workspace/target/release/binary \
    /usr/local/bin/

FROM docker.io/debian:12.1-slim as example-service
COPY --from=build \
    /home/root/workspace/target/release/example-service \
    /usr/local/bin
ENTRYPOINT [ "example-service" ]

FROM docker.io/debian:12.1-slim
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libelf-dev && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY --from=build \
    /usr/local/bin \
    /usr/local/bin/
COPY docker/configs configs
COPY docker/scripts scripts
```

I use `docker compose build` to build the images. However, that leads to the following error (implying that the WORKDIR is not available for the second stage build?):

```
failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref 0687bf79-e5fa-4ea1-9f75-46a52cb9501c::stlqysxbl0pkzy1ijsffcgjgv: failed to walk /mydata/local/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount3152819150/home/root/workspace/target/release: lstat /mydata/local/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount3152819150/home/root/workspace/target/release: no such file or directory
```

However, if I comment the lines caching the target dir (i.e. the lines `--mount=type=cache,target=/home/root/workspace/target`), it works. Is this a problem with caching the mounts or is there something wrong with my Dockerfile?

Answer (score 2):

I have had this issue as well on two different platforms (Docker Desktop for Windows and Podman).

Firstly, cache mounts were added to the `buildkit` builder in Dockerfile syntax 1.2 (are you using BuildKit to build your image?). So you need to add the syntax version to the top of your Dockerfile.

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.2
FROM docker.io/rust:1.71.0-slim-bookworm as build
# other commands ...
```

This fixed the issue for me on Docker Desktop for Windows.

For Podman, apparently run cache mounts are only made available during the `RUN` command and not baked into the actual image. So anything you need from the cache should be copied outside of it as part of the command.

Using your example:

```
# copy the binary to someplace outside the cache
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/usr/local/cargo/registry \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/home/root/workspace/target \
    cargo build --release --all-features \
        && cp /home/root/workspace/target/release/binary /usr/local/bin/

FROM docker.io/debian:12.1-slim as example-service

# copy the binary you pulled outside of the cache
COPY --from=build /usr/local/bin/binary /usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please, before mount line add the below command to show the current working directory and its content

```
RUN echo "Current Working Directory: ${PWD}" && ls -lR
```

Most likely wrong path